# SQL Server 2012 Installation Error

Tags: installation, sql-server-2012

I am getting this error when I try to install SQL server 2012.  Any help would be appreciated.

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.1833",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070BC9.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due the fact that you C++ library got corrupted. For this you can try to repair the .Net framework by doing the following:
a.    Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
b.    In the Currently installed programs list, click Microsoft .NET Framework, and then click Change/Remove.
c.    Click Repair, and then click Next.

If this doesn't help can you provide more information about the server/computer, installation logs.